# WCF When to create a End Point

Tags: wcf, endpoints

I have a WCF service which has  (at the current time) One endpoint defined, to a IMyService
which implements about 20 IDataTypeService which has the DB interfaces for the objects.

The service is pretty high usage and I am having occasional error re timeout and other high use errors.

I am looking for information as to whether to create new end points for the service for the more active data objects, and what benefits (if any) in doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating new endpoints won't help performance necessarily. Like any performance problem, the first step is to find out what the problem is!

The second step is to solve the problem.

In this case, the solution might be getting a new computer to run a second copy of the service on, and then using load balancing. But additional endpoints on the same machine won't help.